# DAX formula to remove non-printing characters

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

The DAX function TRIM() removes only spaces, and DAX doesn't have a CLEAN() function. In the TRIM() documentation it references: "see Remove spaces and nonprinting characters from text", but there's no link. And I'm coming up empty when searching.

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: Excel PowerPivot

Comment: Office 365 ProPlus.  SUBSTITUTE would work, but I'd need to use UNICHAR and that doesn't seem to be implemented in PowerPivot...(?)

Comment: DAX is not designed for this type of operations. It's an interactive reporting language, not data processing language. For data transformations, people typically use PowerQuery (available both in Power Pivot and PowerBI). Pre-process your data in PowerQuery before loading it into the model. PQ has a language called "M", which has a function you need: TEXT.CLEAN

Comment: In my case it's not a data transformation, per se. I'm defining a DAX measure in which I need to compare against the column value with a specific character removed.  DAX does have text functions, but UNICHAR is not yet implemented in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the query editor, under the Transform ribbon, you should see Format with a dropdown. There you will find Trim, Clean, lowercase, uppercase etc.